# surrounding a function with actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, asp.net-core

I am developing an Asp.net MVC application, and I  have created an error handling system that forces me to create the following code per function in my BLL.

```
try
{
   ...
   _unitOfWork.Save(nameof(Function));
}
catch
{
   if (rollbackTo != null)
   {
      _unitOfWork.RollbackToSave(rollbackTo);
   }
   else
   {
       _unitOfWork.Rollback();
   }
   throw;
}
```

this basically allows me to manage my transactions per request, and manage the transaction's error handling without my Controllers knowing about the actual way that this is being done - it only allows it to decide whether or not the transaction will continue (`rollbackTo` parameter)

What I am wondering is, is there a way for me not to have to write this piece of code over and over? I thought about just throwing an exception, and then handle it in my pipeline - but since I need to return a valueable response to the user, and not just a 500 code - this isn't really an option. I thought about maybe creating a base class that calls and abstract method - and implementing it per function - but that won't work either, since the parameters can change. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly standard.

For example, in the base class

```
public void DoSomethingAndRollbackThenThrow(Action<IUnitOfWork> action)
{
   try
  {
   ...
    action(_unitOfWork);
  }
  catch
  {
   if (rollbackTo != null)
   {
      _unitOfWork.RollbackToSave(rollbackTo);
   }
   else
   {
       _unitOfWork.Rollback();
   }
   throw;
 }
}
```

And then you can call it from derived class like so

```
public void DoSomethingSpecific()
{
    base.DoSomethingAndRollbackThenThrow(unitOfWork => {
    _unitOfWork.Save(nameof(Function));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AOP(Aspect Oriented Programming) framework.
You can "weave" some functionalities to your methods with just implementing for one time and adding some attributes.

More about AOP:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

An easy-to-use open source AOP Framework:
https://github.com/AntyaDev/KingAOP

There are also a bunch of alternatives (both commercial and open source). Google may give you good results about alternatives.